# Can a int value added to a float value?

Tags: c

```
/**Program for internal typecasting of the compiler**/
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float b = 0;
    // The Second operand is a integer value which gets added to first operand 
    // which is of float type.  Will the second operand be typecasted to float?
    b = (float)15/2 + 15/2;   
    printf("b is %f\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT : b is 14.500000

Comment: Of course you can add an `int` to `float`. C will convert the `int` to `float` before adding. However, in the expression `(float)15/2 + 15/2`, the first `15/2` will be calculated as `float` and the second `15/2` will be an *integer division first*, and that result converted to *float*. So you'll be adding 7.5+7. You need to apply `float` to it as well: `b = (float)15/2 + (float)15/2`.

Comment: Yes,I could understand that my question is can a integer type be added with a float type?

Comment: Read my last comment completely.

Comment: Even If I am not applying float to the second operand will it be automatically typecasted to float?

Comment: The expression `(float)15/2 + 15/2` is equal to `(15.0f / 2) + (15 / 2)`, which is equal to `7.5f + 7` which is equal to `14.5f`. One division is floating point, the other is integer. The end result of the *addition* will be floating point.

Comment: @Jaivvignesh please read my first comment carefully. I answered that question already.

Comment: @lurker Thank you...So whenever a operation is performed between a float and an int the lower datatype (i.e. here int) will automatically typecasted to float...?

Comment: You should probably read more about [*implicit conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

Comment: Yes, that is basically what happens. And it occurs at each level of grouping. So the second `15/2` is division of two integers, so no conversion occurs for that division. Conversion occurs when the integer result of that division gets added to a float, so the result of the division is only then converted to float. See the great link that @Someprogrammerdude provided.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude@lurker Thank you guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an integral value can be added to a float value.

The basic math operations (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`), when given an operand of type `float` and `int`, the `int` is converted to `float` first.

So `15.0f + 2` will convert `2` to `float` (i.e. to `2.0f`) and the result is `17.0f`.

In your expression `(float)15/2 + 15/2`, since `/` has higher precedence than `+`, the effect will the same as computing `((float)15/2) + (15/2)`.

`(float)15/2` explicitly converts `15` to `float` and therefore implicitly converts `2` to float, yielding the final result of division as `7.5f`.

However, `15/2` does an integer division, so produces the result `7` (there is no implicit conversion to `float` here).

Since `(float)15/2` has been computed as a float, the value `7` is then converted to `float` before addition.  The result will therefore be `14.5f`.

**Note:**  floating point types are also characterised by finite precision and rounding error that affects operations.  I've ignored that in the above (and it is unlikely to have a notable effect with the particular example anyway).

**Note 2:**   Old versions of C (before the C89/90 standard) actually converted `float` operands to `double` in expressions (and therefore had to convert values of type `double` back to `float`, when storing the result in a variable of type `float`).   Thankfully the C89/90 standard fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

**Rule of thumb:** When doing an arithmetic calculation between two different built-in types, the "smaller" type will be converted into the "larger" type.

`double` > `float` > `long long`(C99) > `long` > `short` > `char`.

```
b = (float)15/2 + 15/2;
```

Here the first part, `(float)15/2` is equivalent to `15.0f / 2`. Because an operation involving a "larger" type and a "smaller" type will yield a result in the "larger" type, `(float)15/2` is 7.500000, or `7.5f`.

When it comes to `15/2`, since both operands are integers, the operation is done only on integer level. Therefore the decimal point is stripped (from int), and only gives 7 as a result.

So the expression is calculated into

```
b = 7.5f + 7;
```

No doubt you'll have `14.500000` as the final result, because it's exactly `14.5f`.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = (float)15/2 + 15/2;
```

The first one`((float)15/2)` will work fine. The second one will also work but will be converted into an integer first, so you will lose precision. Like:

```
  b = (float)15/2 + 15/2;
  b = 7.500000f + 7
  b = 14.500000
```

Comment: Note that `7.500000` has type `double` in C.   To have type `float`, there needs to be an `f` suffix  (i.e.  `7.500000f`).

Comment: The last line should be `b = 14.500000f`. You may want to correct it again (missing `f` suffix).

Comment: @¡Bug but compiler not print suffix.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth asking: if an integer value could *not* be added to floating-point value, what would the symptom be?

1. Compiler issues error or warning message.
2. Something gets truncated; you don't get the result you want.
3. Undefined behavior: you might or might not get the result you want, and the compiler might or might not warn you about it.

But in fact none of these things happen.  When you add an integer to a floating-point value, the compiler automatically converts the integer to a floating-point value so it can do the addition that way, and this is perfectly well defined.  For example, if you have the code

```
double d = 7.5;
int i = 7;
double result = d + i;
```

the compiler interprets this just as if you had written

```
double result = d + (double)i;
```

And it works this way for just about all operations: the same logic is applied when you subtract, multiply, or divide a floating-point value and an integer.

And it works this way for just about all types.  If you add a long int and an int, the plain int automatically gets converted to a long.

As a general rule (and I really can't think of too many exceptions), the compiler always wants to do arithmetic on two values of the same type.  So whenever you have two values of different type, the compiler will just about always convert one of them for you.  The full set of rules for how it does this are rather elaborate, but they're all supposed to make sense, and do what you want.  The full set of rules is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, and if you do a Google search on that phrase you'll find lots of explanations.

One case that does *not* necessarily do what you want is when the two variables are *not* different types.  In particular, if the two variables are both integers, and the operation you're doing is division, the compiler doesn't have to convert anything: it divides the integer by the integer, *discarding any remainder*, and gives you an integer result.  So if you have

```
int i = 1;
int j = 2;
int k = i / j;
```

then `k` ends up containing 0.  And if you have

```
double d = i / j;
```

then `d` ends up containing 0 also, because the compiler follows exactly the same rules when performing the division; it doesn't "peek outside" to see that it's going to need a floating-point result.

---

P.S. I said, "As a general rule, the compiler always wants to do arithmetic on two values of the same type", and I said I couldn't think of too many exceptions.  But if you're curious, two exceptions are the `<<` and `>>` operators.  If you have `x << y`, where `x` is a long int and `y` is a plain int, the compiler does *not* have to convert `y` to a long int first.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number1;
float number2,sum;
setbuf(stdout,NULL);
printf("enter 2 numbers");
scanf("%d%f",&number1,&number2);
sum=number1+number2;

printf("Your Result is %f",sum);
```